# Invalid Token Error: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, json-web-signature

I was trying to decode token created through jwt, so that I can access values in my react page and and use it.But for some reason it shows
"InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"   this error, I really need help on this, thankyou very much in advance to whoever answers this.

**Front-End in react.js,decoding the token**

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
const token=localStorage.usertoken

const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

setinfo({
   id:decoded._id,
   email:decoded.email,
   username:decoded.username,
   
})


 },[])
```

**Back-end node.js**

```js
router.get("/info",authenticateToken,(req,res)=>{

    UserProfile.findOne({_id: req.user._id})
            .then(user=>{
                console.log(user);
                if(user){
                    res.json(user)
                } else {
                    res.send("User does not exist")
                }
                
                
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                res.send("error:"+err);
            })
        
})

function authenticateToken(req,res,next){

const authHeader= req.headers['authorization']
const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')

if(token == null) return res.sendStatus(401)

jwt.verify(token,secretkey,(err,user)=>{

    if(err) return res.sendStatus(403)
    req.user = user
    next();
})
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you use replace. You need to show that code. if you didn't implement the replace method then you should check the stack trace and find out what function did. then make sure that function is getting exactly what it needs in it's args

Comment: I haven't used replace anywhere in my code, it's used in index.js of jwt-decode in node modules package

Answer (score 5):

I found this article that worked for me:

https://www.onooks.com/invalid-token-specified-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined/

In summery it suggest that you clear your browser’s local storage cache using the developer tools "F12" and go to Storage\Local Storage, right click and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are accessing the token from localStorage is wrong.
Instead of

```
localStorage.usertoken
```

use

```
localStorage.getItem("userToken")
```

considering you have set user token by

```
localStorage.setItem("userToken", token_received_from_backend);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I also got the same error. In my case, I have got one mistake. In Localstorage please remove the token variable and refresh the page**

- In My case, the local-storage variable name is **myToken** is **undefined**, so I deleted the variable and refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

When you call the cloud function, Try to add the full function url in the post request instead of "/login".

Answer (score 0):

for me i tryed remove useState()
and change with  veriable
exemple :

```js
// const [user , setUser] = useState({}); # Remove This <
let user; // Use This 


// cooking-login jwt
    const jwtlogin = (mytoken) => {
        // Decode JWT token
        const decoded = jwtDecode(mytoken)

        // set emails State
        user = decoded;
        // set cookie
        cookies.set("jwt_auth",mytoken, {
            expires: new Date(decoded.exp * 1000),
        })
    }
```

Just This and Thanks